# apache rewrite specific htaccess redirections

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with my .htaccess redirections.

Say I want to change

```
http://www.domain.com/login.php
```

into

```
http://www.domain.com/login
```

or

```
http://www.domain.com/login/
```

my .htaccess works with "www.domain.com/login"

but when using "www.domain.com/login/" (with a slash in the end) the css and images get all messed.

my .htaccess is as follows

```
# Turns on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^loginFailed/?$ failed.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also I have a login.php that directs to failed.php when the user enters the wrong username/password combination. I tried setting it up using the same method.

But when I tested starting from http://www.domain.com/login entering a wrong combination directs me to

```
http://www.domain.com/failed.php
```

instead of the desired http://www.domain.com/loginFailed

how can I solve this problem.

Much appreciated!!

Comment: What does your URL to images look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be *not* in your RewriteRules, but in your `Php` code. Are you **sure** that the redirection when the login fails, *in your Php code* is for sure `loginFailed` (instead of `failed.php`)?

I would suggest to check you Php code first ;)

Comment: You're sometimes faster than me about RewriteRules =)